# Word for bringing into agreement

Tags: single-word-requests

If there are two points that disagree, is there a word for the act of making them seem as if they are, in fact, in agreement? I've heard "resolve" used in this context, but it doesn't quite work for what I'm looking for.

"Rather than explaining the difference between the two texts, the commentaries seek to ?? them so that they appear to express the same opinion."

Comment: Not writing an answer because I think this one is doomed for lack of research. ["If you _reconcile_ two beliefs, facts, or demands that seem to be opposed or completely different, you find a way in which they can both be true or both be successful."](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reconcile)

Comment: Also consider *align*.

Comment: @Cascabel *Reconcile* is actually what is **not** being done here. Try to get the drift of the context.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I think reconcile or align both work well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[**Reconcile**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reconcile):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1 a** : to restore to friendship or harmony • *reconciled* the factions
> **b** : SETTLE, RESOLVE • *reconcile* differences
>
> **2** : to make consistent or congruous • *reconcile* an ideal with reality

---

**Update**: Based on some comments, here is the word inserted into the example sentence that was given:

> Rather than explaining the difference between the two texts, the commentaries seeks to **reconcile** them so that they appear to express the same opinion.

Even if *how* the opinion expressed is different, they are being analyzed in such a way that seem to be in accord at some level despite that.

In this way, it's the disharmony that's resolved.

This is like political adversaries who can reconcile their differences in order to come together at a summit to discuss mutually acceptable courses of action. Although they still disagree with each other, the conflict that has kept them apart has been reconciled.

---

Here also is the Collins definition of [**reconcile**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reconcile):

> If you reconcile two beliefs, facts, or demands that seem to be opposed or completely different, you find a way in which they can both be true or both be successful.

Comment: *Reconcile* is actually what is **not** being done here. Try to get the drift of the context.

Comment: @ Thank you, @Cascabel. I had not actually used the Collins definition originally, but I've added it as it provides some additional clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "interpret"?

> Rather than explaining the difference between the two texts, the
>   commentaries seek to **interpret** them so that they appear to express
>   the same opinion.

You gave no examples so I have invented a simple one.

> Text A. People came to the party to meet each other and enjoy the
>   food.
>
> Text B. People came to the party to eat their fill of the free food.

These two texts appear to disagree about the reason people came to the party.

If the object is to praise the party, they could be ***interpreted*** to mean

> There is no doubt that the party served excellent food.

without discussing why they are different.

Comment: I like interprete. I think 'seeks to equate' might work too.